# How to restrict certain fields in a model based on the user in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, user-permissions

I have a *Department* table. And a *Student* table which references the department table. I have also created a custom user model,*UserAugment*, to add department field to the default User model.

```
class Department(models.Model):
    dname = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dname

class UserAugment(AbstractUser):
     department = models.ForeignKey(Department,null=True,blank=True)
     objects = UserManager()


class Student(models.Model):
    sname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    usn = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    sem = models.IntegerField()

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s' % (self.usn,self.sname)
```

Now, I need to create users, who would have a department attached to them. And each user should be given permission for add/edit/view for students belonging to their department. And I'm having a nightmare doing that. Was it really simple? Thanks for any help that would pour out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,this was what worked finally for me,

```
 class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     def get_queryset(self, request):
         qs = super(StudentAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
         if request.user.is_superuser:
             return qs
         return qs.filter(dept=request.user.department)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage permission control in the admin:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return self.user_has_permission(request, obj)

    def user_has_permission(self, request, obj):
        if hasattr(request.user, 'department') and obj is not None:
            return request.user.department == obj.dept
        return False
```

You can implement the `edit` and `delete` permissions the same way.

Comment: For one part, it gives 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'obj'. For the second part, I don't believe my admin.py is set up properly. Do I need to write any corresponding code for my UserAugment() in admin.py? Something like, admin.site.register(UserAugment,UserAdmin)

Comment: I have pasted UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) in admin.py.. I hope that was a typo when you mentioned UserAdmin(models.ModelAdmin)

Comment: Yes, sorry, fixed it. And yes, you need admin.site.register(UserAugment, UserAdmin)